# Change xticklabels fontsize of seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is my question:
I plot 7 variable's coefficient using sns.clustermap()

- x/y tickslabel seems really small(In my case, s1,s2,... s9)

#### My attempt

- `label='big` ==> no effect
- plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=12)  ===> cbar label has changed, but the x/y axes looks the same.

#### Add

My code:

```
 ds =  pd.read_csv("xxxx.csv")
 corr = ds.corr().mul(100).astype(int)
 
 cmap = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=210, h_pos=350, s=90, l=30, as_cmap=True)

 sns.clustermap(data=corr_s, annot=True, fmt='d',cmap = "Blues",annot_kws={"size": 16},)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Or just use the set_xticklabels:

```
g = sns.clustermap(data=corr_s, annot=True, fmt='d',cmap = "Blues")
g.ax_heatmap.set_xticklabels(g.ax_heatmap.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 16)
```

To get different colors for the ticklabels:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, corr_s.shape[0]))
for i, ticklabel in enumerate(g.ax_heatmap.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()):
    ticklabel.set_color(colors[i])
```

Comment: Can we have different colours for the labels?

Comment: More flexible solution I'd say.

Answer (score 87):

Consider calling `sns.set(font_scale=1.4)` before plotting your data. This will scale all fonts in your legend and on the axes.

My plot went from this,
[image]

To this,

[image]

Of course, adjust the scaling to whatever you feel is a good setting.

Code:

```
sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=210, h_pos=350, s=90, l=30, as_cmap=True)
sns.clustermap(data=corr, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap="Blues", annot_kws={"size": 16})
```

Comment: Can we have different colours for the labels?

Comment: Thank you! This might seem obvious, but you can also make font smaller by using `sns.set(font_scale=0.5)`, specifically using a value less than one.

Comment: No, this doesn't provide the right answer because this will rescale **all** the texts, also the title. What can I do if I want to *only* rescale the xticklabels?